# What is embark?

Tags: dapp-development, testing, embark, framework, dapp-debugging

What is the [embark](https://github.com/iurimatias/embark-framework) framework? Who can use it, who should use it?

And what are the benefits?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Embark is a development framework. It's used to make development faster and more streamlined by providing a set of tools / functionalities to make you more productive.

In the case of embark it makes/will make the process of creating a dapp faster by simplifying the interaction between your app front end and the contract (e.g. running your own blockchain for development purposes out of the box, even if it's already pretty easy to run your own node, comes ethereum ready as far as front end, etc.)

Any person willing to make dapps should use it at some point IMO (or another framework) simply for the productivity value but also to test your dapp etc. As for using it now, ethereum technology being quite young I would still suggest first learning ethereum " the hard way " to better use it in the future and to understand what you are doing.

There is also [Truffle](https://github.com/consensys/truffle) that I've heard about but I didn't quite look into it yet as I have just started checking embark and am still doing things framework free.

Comment: Truffle and Embark are essentially the same thing. If you're looking for an interesting build tool, I'd recommend using Dapple as a contract package manager.

Comment: @jayD I have nearly finished my first dApp using Truffle and Solidity.  I'm only using Truffle for compile, deploy, and debug.  I am not using Drizzle, React, or any other frameworks/tools.  At what point should I considers refactoring my app,  a big job I assume, to use Embark?  I've noticed a I spend a lot of time writing infrastructure to manage the extremely complex, asynchronous, client side and server side operations that have to be deferred until a transaction is mined/confirmed.  Does Embark help with that?  What about transaction retries when gas is too low?

Answer (score -1):

Technically truffle is very handy and logical because it helps you to see and understand the compile , making json files and deploy. after the deployment you can copy json of the smart contracts and use it in the front chain

Comment: The question is about embark not truffle.